# Need to query specific dates to get a full year

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT                                                 
  ALL       OHORDT, (OHORD#), (OHTTN$)                 
  FROM      ASTDTA.OEORHdoh T01                          
  WHERE     OHORDD BETWEEN 20160117 AND 20160123       
    AND     OHHLDC <> 'DCL'                            
    AND     OHOSTC <> 'CN'
```

This query is fine but we need to refine the dates as, 
Total Orders are obtained from running the query DAYBYREPSM for previous day and for the following day of the pervious year.  Example 2/1/16 - run query for 2/1/16 and 2/2/15.

To get for previous day, I should be able to use Currentdate - 1. But not sure how to get the previous year and following day.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? That's pretty important when dealing with dates as date functions are often vendor specific.

Comment: We are using db2 here to use in a Crystal reports.

Comment: `currentdate - 1 YEAR + 1 DAY`?